# How would i unit test this class?

Tags: java, class, testing

A bank account has a balance that can be changed by 
deposits and withdrawals.

Constructs a bank account with a zero balance.

Constructs a bank account with a given balance.
@param initialBalance the initial balance

Deposits money into the bank account.
@param amount the amount to deposit

Withdraws money from the bank account.
@param amount the amount to withdraw

Gets the current balance of the bank account.
@return the current balance

```
 public class BankAccount
        {
           private double balance;

           public BankAccount()
           {
              balance = 0;
           }

           public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
           {
              balance = initialBalance;
           }

           public void deposit(double amount)
           {
              balance = balance + amount;
           }

           public void withdraw(double amount)
           {
              balance = balance - amount;
           }

           public double getBalance()
           {
              return balance;
           }
        }
```

Comment: How have you _tried_ to unit test the class? Please show some research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another Class Main.java where you use the `public static void main(String[] args)`method, create an Object of the class you created and use corresponding methods.
Sample Output:
0.0
500.0
250.0

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create an Object
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();
        // use some Methods
        System.out.println(ba.getBalance()); 
        ba.deposit(500);
        System.out.println(ba.getBalance());
        ba.withdraw(250);
        System.out.println(ba.getBalance());
    }
}
```